# JqueryUI icon show up on new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am tring do add a jqueryui dialog to my webpage, but when it shows up the close icon come on a new line instead of being on the same line as the title. Its the same problem in both Chrome, IE and Firefox.
I have tried to remove my custom css to make sure that it wasnt that which messed it up.

Screenshot can be seen here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/653527/screenshtodialog.png

The code can be seen on the frontpage of this site:
http://www.hvemskylderhvem.dk/

Click on the picture. It can also be seen on the button with the icon.

Thanks.

(I have the some problem with jqueryui buttons where the text and the icon also shows up on different lines)

Comment: Does it happen on every browser? Could you post some code pls?

Comment: It happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE. I have now added a link to the website, so all code is avaiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing some styles form the jQuery UI stylesheet. In the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) I found this style declaration:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: .3em;
    top: 50%;
    width: 19px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

Try to add the original jQuery UI stylesheets. Maybe you can use [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to adopt your styles.

Comment: I downloaded the ui stylesheet again and it helped! Thank you very much